# What is the purpose of a test environment for rendering and where can I get one?

Tags: rendering, lighting, hdri, .exr

I am learning Blender and I see a lot of videos where people use like "test environments" to test lighting, reflection, etc.

Something like this (seen in Blender Guru Video)
[image]

I was wondering if they have a specific name and what is their purpose (above testing light and reflections)?

If someone knows where to download one (for free) would be great.

Comment: https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/ Maybe try here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're referring to HDRIs.

There are things to know about how to use them. Among all the tutorials out there, you should watch the [Image-based lighting course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2aDImegRwZE1XFZyqwAhLzsIlo8ju9R1) by Gleb Alexandrov. It's the most up to date and best one.

Now here's where you can find some good ones for free :

- [Free bundle](https://hdrihaven.com/bundle.php?b=free_bundle) on *HDRI Haven* plus [all those marked with the green CCO](https://hdrihaven.com/hdris.php) in the corner
- in the [demo version](https://www.blenderguru.com/prolighting-skies-demo/?rq=pro%20lighting%20skies) of *Pro-lighting : Skies*
- [Freebies](https://hdrmaps.com/freebies) on *HDR Maps*

Less high-res (usable for lighting and reflections but not for direct background viewing) :

- [free set](https://hdr-sets.com/product/free-set/) on *HDR Sets*
- a bunch on [*CG Advertising*](http://www.cgadvertising.com/pages/free-materials/hdr-maps.php)
- all skies on [*HDRI Skies*](http://hdri-skies.com/) in 2K resolution

I guess you're pretty much covered. Have fun Blending.